When is a fiberwise-very-ample line bundle on a fibered surface also $k$-very ample?
Let $g : Y\rightarrow\text{Spec }k$ be a smooth proper curve, and let $f : X\rightarrow Y$ be a family of stable curves. Consider the line bundle $\mathcal{L} := \omega^{\otimes 3}_{X/Y}$. It's known that the restrictions of $\mathcal{L}$ to fibers of $X/Y$ are very ample.
(a) Is $\mathcal{L}$ very ample relative to $f$? (related question)
(b) Is $\mathcal{L}$ very ample relative to $g\circ f$?
Are there reasonable conditions on $f,g$ that would guarantee these properties? (I'm particularly interested in (b)).
Remarks:

By stacks 0D2S, one can deduce that $\mathcal{L}$ is ample on $X_U$, for any open affine $U\subset Y$.
To show that $\mathcal{L}$ is very $f$-very ample, it would suffice to show that $\mathcal{L}$ is fpqc-locally (on $Y$) $f$-very ample. See Remy's answer here


That's not what the stacks tag says - it says $\mathcal L$ is ample on the inverse image of an open subset of $Y$.

@WillSawin Good point. I was thinking in my mind that $Y$ was affine, which is of course not the case here. I've edited accordingly. Thanks!

Think of the case where $X = C \times Y$. Then your line bundle is the pullback of $\omega_C^3$, so it is trivial on all fibers of $X \to C$, and therefore not ample.
